# Most affordable way to create a "T" connection between two pieces of EMT galvanized metal conduit for creating shade panels

Tags: walls, outdoor, metal

I started a thread about extending the height of my fence to create more privacy. That thread is here:

[Inexpensive ideas to extend the height of my fence cinderblock wall outdoors](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/214327/inexpensive-ideas-to-extend-the-height-of-my-fence-cinderblock-wall-outdoors/214379#214379)

I am going the route of using EMT as per suggested by ojait who answered that question. The thing I'd like to do is create a horizontal support by creating a "T" connection at the top of each post so that I can run an EMT tube along the top as a way to attach the fabric. I feel compelled to do this so that I have more support on those occasional windy days we experience. This would be my way of hoping that fabric won't rip in the wind.

My question is what is a very inexpensive way to achieve the "T" connections I'm looking to create? I am currently using 1/2" EMT as the vertical rods connected to the fence. I thought what I could do is get 3/4" EMT pipe and then find the appropriate 1/2" drill bit and drill holes along the 3/4" EMT tube so that they meet up at every vertical EMT tube attacked to my wall. I would pop this into the vertical rods. I thought of using epoxy to help secure the connections in place. Then I'm going to wrap the fabric up and down both sides and secure them to the vertical and horizontal EMT rods using pan screws. So the tension of the fabric from the top and bottom to hold it all in place.

I did find these EMT connectors that would work. They only come in 3/4" size but have an adapter sleeve for only ten cents per connection to make them work with 1/2" EMT:

[image]

["T" connectors](https://makerpipe.com/collections/modular-pipe-fittings/products/t-connector?gclid=Cj0KCQiAmL-ABhDFARIsAKywVae9167LcU9iSvwisthyQjugJTTN_XbPaCOZRAot4f_m13YGgbCRYgwaApAyEALw_wcB)

They look really nice but I like I said earlier, I plan to wrap my fabric along the backside and along my side (the front) so the EMT will be housed inside of fabric, so to speak, without being visible. In case you're wondering why I'm doubling the fabric in this way it's because just one single layer doesn't create enough privacy. I just discovered this after I received my fabric in the mail. Not to mention, these "T" connectors being $3 will run me an additional $100 or a bit more in cost that I'd like to try and avoid.

If my idea of creating a 1/2" hole would work, what drill bit would I look for that would work with metal that is curved? Or any ideas? I'm open. I'd just like to get this done as cheaply and as quickly yet as well done as possible.

Comment: Intuition tells me that drilling a 1/2" hole into 3/4" conduit will significantly weaken the conduit possibly leading to it bending and breaking at the hole. Putting a gusset of larger conduit around the 3/4" at the point of the hole, epoxying or welding the two together, then drilling through both might be sufficient for strengthening the joint. Of course, if you (or know someone who) can weld, simply welding them together may be a good option to begin with. Your t-connectors _look_ really nice, and may make a better joint in the long run - it may well be worth it.